# how to access external data sources such as MySQL instead of webpages?

Tags: solidity, chainlink

I am a novice at Etheuerm. I want to know how to access external data sources such as MySQL or excel through chainlink instead of webpages

Answer (score 0):

[33sir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17863075/33sir)

Welcome to the amazing Ethereum world :)

Chainlink is a flexible framework that can retrieve data from any API and connect with existing systems.

I like the examples that the [Chainlink website](https://chain.link/) present when you scroll down, how to get weather data or sports data, for example. It is connecting with API in the external world.

So in you case, you need to create an API to connect with your data sources, like MySQL or excel.

Here you can get more info how to [call any external API](https://docs.chain.link/docs/request-and-receive-data/)

It is not necessary a webpage, but you will [make a GET request](https://docs.chain.link/docs/make-a-http-get-request/) to a service that you will create.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! And,can i get data from postgresSQL by chainlink core adapter?